# Thread dump Quarkus native

Tags: performance, quarkus-native

How can we use thread dump and heap dump when we deploy a native Quarkus service in the k8s cluster?
I need to check exactly which block of code is facing performance issues.

Thanks,
Tam

Cannot find jmap or jstack inside K8S pod, ps command not found in K8S pod

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can if your GraalVM is recent enough, see this [Quarkus guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/native-reference#heap-dumps):

> Starting with GraalVM 22.2.0 it is possible to create heap dumps upon request, e.g. kill -SIGUSR1 . Support for dumping the heap dump upon an out of memory error will follow up.

Seems to be linked to this section of the [reference manual of the GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/NativeImageHeapdump/).

For the `PID` it may be simply `1`.